# как добавить строку в список, чтобы она не удалялась при повторном запуске?

Tags: java

запускаю. добавляю. пишет, что строка добавилась, но при новом запуске как-будто ничего не было.
надо чтобы она сохранялась в списке и ее индекс увеличивался на 1

задание звучит так:
Команды LIST, ADD, EDIT, DELETE. LIST должен выводить дела с их порядковыми номерами. ADD - добавлять дело в конец списка или дело на определённое место, сдвигая остальные дела вперёд, если указать номер. EDIT - заменять дело с указанным номером. DELETE - удалять. Примеры команд:
    LIST

```
ADD Какое-то дело

ADD 4 Какое-то дело на четвёртом месте

EDIT 3 Новое название дела

DELETE 7
```

То что сумела сделать

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> todoList = new ArrayList<>(){{
            add(0,"Почистить зубы");
            add(1,"Сделать зарядку");
            add(2,"Выпить стакан воды");
            add(3,"Приготовить завтрак");
            add(4,"Отправится на работу");//Добавляем пункт по индексу 4
        }};
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        var str = "LIST";
        System.out.print("Чтобы посмотреть содержимое списка введите команду LIST : ");
        if(sc.hasNext()) { // возвращает истину если с потока ввода можно считать слово
            str = sc.next(); // считывает слово с потока ввода и сохраняем в переменную
            System.out.println(str);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Вы ввели не правильную команду");
        }
        for (String item : todoList){
            System.out.println(item);
        }
        var strAdd = "ADD";
        System.out.print("Чтобы добавить новое дело в список введите команду ADD : ");
        if(sc.hasNext()) { // возвращает истину если с потока ввода можно считать слово
            strAdd = sc.next(); // считывает слово с потока ввода и сохраняем в переменную
            System.out.println(strAdd + '\n' + "Введите дело которое хотите добавить в список : ");
            todoList.add(sc.next());
            System.out.println("Новое дело добавленно в список! \n");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Вы ввели не правильную команду");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы советовал решать данную проблему сохраняя список при выходе из программы или при добавлении нового дела сохранять обновленный список. Сохранять вероятнее всего нужно будет в файл, делается это так:

```
public void save(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
    for (Club club : clubs)
         pw.println(club); 
    pw.close();
}
```

Нужно только заменить данный массив на ваш и так же например передавать в данную функцию массив с данными, потому что насколько я вижу он у вас не в виду глобальной переменной. Дальше при входе в программу вы проверяете есть ли файл, если его нет значит программа запускается впервые и вы сохраняете данный  массив, если же файл есть то вы считываете данные оттуда и проверяете их. Считать данные можно так:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("filepath"));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (s.hasNext()){
    list.add(s.next());
}
s.close();
```

И дальше уже проводите проверку данных из файла и действия над ними. [Первоисточник_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111496/java-how-can-i-write-my-arraylist-to-a-file-and-read-load-that-file-to-the) и [первоисточник_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343689/java-reading-a-file-into-an-arraylist).